# add elements of html file inside iframe to the DOM tree of the original file

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

I have `test.php` file that contains iframe which gets its source from `iframe.html` when button `click` is clicked.

However I want to apply some javascript code on the elements of the file inside iframe (`iframe.html`) but nothing happening, here is my code:

tesp.php file:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>test</title>
</head>
<body>
<input type="button" value="Click" id="fill_iframe"/>
<br>
<iframe id="iframe" src="" style="width: 200px; height: 100px">hello</iframe>
<br>
<div class="front">
    <a href="#">outside frame</a>
</div>
<br>
<input type="button" value="change color" id="log"/>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.js"></script>
<script>
    $("#fill_iframe").click(function () {
    $("#iframe")[0].src = "iframe.html";
    });
    $("#log").click(function () {

    $('.front a').css('color', 'red');
    console.log($("#iframe"));
    });

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

and the iframe.html file:

```
<html>
   <head>

    </head>
   <body>
      <div class="front">
        <a href="#">inside frame</a>
      </div>

   </body>
</html>
```

when I click the `change color` button, only the outside link is changed.

And when I use `console.log($("#iframe"));`, it has no children? why is that?

What am I missing?

I even tried to use `$("#iframe").load("iframe.html");` nothing changed

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to get inside the iframe document. In jQuery you can do this using

```
jQuery("#iframe").contents().find(".front a").css("color", "red");
```